# Big Oh Notation and Calculating the Running Time for a Triple-Nested For-Loop

Tags: runtime, computer-science, code-analysis, big-o, analysis

In Computer Science, it is very important for Computer Scientists to know how to calculate the running times of algorithms in order to optimize code. For you Computer Scientists, I pose a question.

I understand that, in terms of n, a double-nested for-loop typically has a running time of n<sup>2</sup> and a triple-nested for-loop typically has a running time of n<sup>3</sup>.

However, for a case where the code looks like this, would the running time be n4?

```
x = 0;
for(a = 0; a < n; a++)
    for(b = 0; b < 2a; b++)
        for (c=0; c < b*b; c++)
            x++;
```

I simplified the running time for each line to be virtually (n+1) for the first loop, (2n+1) for the second loop, and (2n)<sup>2</sup>+1 for the third loop. Assuming the terms are multiplied together, and we extract the highest term to find the Big Oh, would the running time be n<sup>4</sup>, or would it still follow the usual running-time of n<sup>3</sup>?

I would appreciate any input. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why would you expect this to be O(n^3)?

Answer (score 7):

You are correct,  n*2n*4n<sup>2</sup> =  O(n<sup>4</sup>).

The triple nested loop only means there will be three numbers to multiply to determine the final Big O - each multiplicand itself is dependent on how much  "processing" each loop does though.

In your case the first loop does O(n) operations, the second one O(2n) = O(n) and the inner loop does O(n<sup>2</sup>) operations, so overall O(n*n*n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>4</sup>).

Comment: added `sup` tags to your powers, hope you don't mind, but I think it's more readable that way.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks! - I didn't know that tag existed, otherwise I would have used it.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, using Sigma Notation, you can obtain this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a question for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

My gut feelings, like BrokenGlass is that it is O(n⁴).

EDIT: [Sum of squares](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm) and [Sum of cubes](http://merganser.math.gvsu.edu/calculus/summation/cubes.html) give a pretty good understanding of what is involved. The answer is a resounding O(n^4): sum(a=0 to n) of (sum(b=0 to 2a) of (b^2)). The inner sum is congruent to a^3. Therefore your outer sum is congruent to n^4.

Pity, I thought you might get away with some log instead of n^4. Never mind.